Identify this asian movie
I saw a small portion of this movie in the year 2000.
It was a new movie at that time.
Language: Asian (not sure which one)
Country: Unknown
Genre: Romance
Plot:
Hero works at some radio station. He meets a girl in a subway. It's an unconditional love story.
He doesn't know her name. He doesn't know what she does, where she's from or any stuff like that.
He meets the same girl some years later at a different place. She doesn't love him. He loves her unconditionally.
She's a terrorist. He's not aware of that in the first half of the movie. I haven't seen the full movie yet. So, don't know the rest of the story.

Are you talking about this hindi movie Dil Se..?
Plot:

Amar Kant Varma (Shahrukh Khan) is a Program Executive for All India Radio. He is dispatched from New Delhi to cover festivities in the northeastern parts of India, and Kashmir. In the midst of rain storm, on his way to board Baraks Valley Express, he comes across a beautiful woman (Manisha Koirala) and is instantly attracted to the stranger. He tries to talk to her at the railway station, but she does not seem to respond, however when he asks if he can get anything for her she says she would like a cup of tea. As Amar goes to get her tea, her train arrives and she boards with three men.

In the movie, Meghna (the lady you're talking about.) is a terrorist and gets close to  Amar and stays in his house only to execute her terrorist attacks as planned but in the end she realizes that she's in love with him too and they both die holding each other while the bomb explodes.
